# How to get a Max Value from a dict in python with multiples elements

Tags: python, json, dictionary, max

I am having a hard time time trying to get the Name of the element with the MAx Value:

Here is the Json example:

```
    {  
   'id':'bbb',
   'project':'8',
   'iteration':'34',
   'created':'2019-03-09T12:58:18.0331802Z',
   'predictions':[  
      {  
         'probability':0.8849932,
         'tagId':'a',
         'tagName':'Dog'
      },
      {  
         'probability':0.11359062,
         'tagId':'b',
         'tagName':'Cat'
      },
      {  
         'probability':0.001416232,
         'tagId':'c',
         'tagName':'Bird'
      }
   ]
}
```

The result I want to return is the tagName "Dog", since 0.8849932 is the Max probability value

Anyone?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `max` function with a key function that returns the value of the `probability` key, and get the value by the key `tagName` from the returning value of the `max` function thereafter:

```
from operator import itemgetter
max(d['predictions'], key=itemgetter('probability'))['tagName']
```

Comment: Work like a charm @blhsing!
Thanks!

Comment: Done Sir! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I generally do this by initially sorting the list of the objects and then picking the first element of the sorted list.
In this case you would do:

```
predictions = dict['predictions']
sorted_list = sorted( predictions, key = lambda i: i['probability'],reverse=True)
print ( sorted_list[0])
```

Comment: Time complexity of `sorted()` is `O(nlogn)` and of `max()` is `O(n)`. You are better off using `max` with the same `key` that you used. `max(predictions, key=lambda i: i['probability'])`

Comment: Yeah! but wont matter too much for small data sets like mentioned in the question.